# How to remove/hide bottom toolbar on Google Drive PDF embeds

Tags: wordpress, pdf, embed

I would like to remove or hide the grey "Page 1/1", etc toolbar that appears when hovering over the image as it is blocking access to some of the links further down. The image is an embed from Google Drive.

I'm no coder but this is what I have so far:

[googleapps domain="drive" dir="file/d/1VK0wQFkxwvAHkLDqa8j0NHIeX3ynoRBB/preview" query="#toolbar=0" width="640" height="500" text-align:center]

Example: https://www.wildeones.com/product-tag/uk-size-m-half/

[image]

Comment: What is that code from/what kind of code is that?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your input. I worked out how to embed the PDF from the WP media library instead and the hover toolbar isn't as disruptive so all good now. https://www.wildeones.com/product-tag/uk-size-a/ - I used this code instead: <iframe src="https://www.wildeones.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Ring-Size-Chart.pdf" width="100%" height="1150px">
    </iframe> - Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to accept and work around that issue by increasing the frame height so injecting a taller height value it may look like this:-

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your input. I worked out how to embed the PDF from the WP media library instead and the hover toolbar isn't as disruptive so all good now. wildeones.com/product-tag/uk-size-a - I used this code instead: <iframe src="wildeones.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Ring-Size-Chart.pdf" width="100%" height="1150px"> </iframe> - Thanks again!